# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when writing to the install path

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm trying to download multiple files from an SFTP server and save them to the install path (or actually, ANY path at the moment just to get it working). However, I get an UnauthorizedAccess Exception no matter where I try to save the files.

As far as was aware, there are no special permissions required to save files to the install dir (Hence why I chose this folder).

```
    Thread myThread = new Thread(delegate() {
        string host;
        string username;
        string password; 

        // Path to folder on SFTP server
        string pathRemoteDirectory = "public_html/uploads/17015/";

        // Path where the file should be saved once downloaded (locally)
        StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        string pathLocalDirectory = localFolder.Path.ToString();

        var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
        methods.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password));
        //TODO - Add SSH Key auth

        var con = new ConnectionInfo(host, 233, username, methods.ToArray());

        using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(con))
        {
            try
            {
                sftp.Connect();

                var files = sftp.ListDirectory(pathRemoteDirectory);

                // Iterate over them
                foreach (SftpFile file in files)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Downloading {0}", file.FullName);

                    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(pathLocalDirectory, file.Name)))
                    {

                        sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);
                        Debug.WriteLine(fileStream);

                    }

                }

                sftp.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception has been caught " + er.ToString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Connection to the server is all fine, the exception occurs on this line.

`using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(pathLocalDirectory, file.Name)))`

I'm must be missing something obvious here but it's worth noting that I've also tried writing to Special Folders like the Desktop, the users Document folder and also direct to the C:/ drive, all with the same exception. I'm also running with Administrator privileges and I have the correct permissions set in the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that SFTP was counting '.' and '..' as files and trying to download those, when obviously '.' is the set SFTP folder and '..' is the previous folder. This was causing a permissions exception, not 100% sure why. Simply iterating over the files to make sure they're not named '.' or '..' fixed the issue. Code below.

```
               sftp.Connect();

                var files = sftp.ListDirectory(pathRemoteDirectory);

                // Iterate over them
                foreach (SftpFile file in files)
                {

                    if (!file.IsDirectory && !file.IsSymbolicLink)
                    {
                        using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(pathLocalDirectory, file.Name)))
                        {
                            sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);
                            Debug.WriteLine(pathLocalDirectory);

                        }
                    }

                    else if (file.Name != "." && file.Name != "..")
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Directory Ignored {0}", file.FullName);
                    }

                    else if (file.IsSymbolicLink)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Symbolic link ignored: {0}", file.FullName);
                    }


                }

                sftp.Disconnect();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems here. The parent folder ("..") reference you answered is one blocker, but that doesn't address the deeper problem that the [InstalledLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation#Windows_ApplicationModel_Package_InstalledLocation) is read-only.

UWP apps do not have direct access to most file system locations. By default they can read and write to their [ApplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData) directory and they can read from (but not write to) the [InstalledLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation#Windows_ApplicationModel_Package_InstalledLocation). The failures you saw for Desktop, Documents, and C:\ are all expected.

Other locations (including Desktop, Documents, and C:) may be granted access by the user either explicitly or via the app's declared capabilities. They can be accessed via the file broker through the StorageFile object.

See the UWP [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) documentation:

> The app's install directory is a read-only location. You can't gain
>   access to the install directory through the file picker.

For the long term you'll want to download your files somewhere else: probably into one of the ApplicationData folders. These folders are the only ones with no special permission requirements for UWP apps.

**So why does this work for you now?**

You're running into a debugging quirk where your app is not fully installed but is staged from your VS project directory. This allows the app to write to the staged install directory, but once it is properly deployed into Program Files\WindowsApps writing to the InstalledLocation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try Path.GetTempPath();. You should have permission there.

When it says you don't have permission, you don't. 8-)

Also, there's no such thing as "no special permissions". Everything requires some level of permission for access.

Comment: Same issue I'm afraid. Literally any path would suffice for this particular purpose, but I can't seem to write to any directory.

Comment: Ahh, I've found the issue. It turns out that SFTP was counting '.' and '..' as files and trying to download those, when obviously '.' is the set SFTP folder and '..' is the previous folder. This was causing a permissions exception, not 100% sure why. Will post the code below for anybody who strolls into a similar issue.